# Is there any way to get results for multiple search types together in facebooksdk v2.0?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using facebooksdk v2.0 for checkins.

I am able to get list of all restaurants successfully using below method.

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPlacesSearchAtCoordinate:aLocationCordinate radiusInMeters:1000 resultsLimit:100 searchText:@"restaurant" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if(error==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"result===%@",result);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"error===%@",error.description);
    }
}];
```

Anybody knows how to search multiple types of places like restaurant,bars,theatre together? I tried passing comma(,) separated but its not working.

Comment: No, you can only search for one term at a time. You can however perform multiple API requests grouped together in a [Batch Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) – that will keep the number of necessary HTTP requests down, and therefor speed things up.

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate it ! But that I have already managed to do. I was looking for work around from sdk usage only.